# GCC 10.2 not accepting an lambda empty lambda as a constexpr std::function<void()>

Tags: c++, gcc

I was playing around with constexpr when I found that GCC rejected this seemingly valid code:

```
#include <functional>

constexpr void test(const std::function<void()>& a) {
    a();    
}

int main() {
    test([](){});
}
```

I went to godbolt, and clang happens to compile this code fine. Is this a bug in GCC? Here is the [godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/TP9dac)

Comment: for me gcc looks ok as call of a() *can* have side effects which violates test() to be constexpr.

Comment: @Klaus I'm not so sure. The lambda definition is visible, and it's clearly constexpr, so I think clang is right here. Also, the error is about the call to `a()`, not the constexpr-ness of `test`.

Comment: Making the function `constexpr void test(void(*a)())` makes even gcc happy so my guess is it has something to do with `std::function`. It lacks a `constexpr` constructor which may be one thing.

Comment: @cigien Even if the call for the lambda is constexpr, is the operator()() of std::function constexpr? I don't believe!

Comment: @cigien does that mean I cant use std::function is constexpr context?

Comment: @Klaus Oh, you're right, it's [not](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator()). Nice catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, `std::function` itself can not be used in `constexpr` environemt, because the `operator()()` and also the constructor of `std::function` is not constexpr.

As this you can use directly a pointer to function, if you have capture less lambdas or you can templatize you function like this in C++20:

```
constexpr void test(auto&& a) {
    a();
}
```

or with explicit template parameters in older C++ standards.

Use `auto` or `auto&` or `auto&&` as needed to allow temporary lambda,  move it in or copy it ( which might be the same after optimizing )

Taken from the comments:

> A constexpr function must have at least one set of inputs that are able to be evaluated in a constant expression - otherwise it's ill formed no diagnostic required*

As clang did not report something did not mean it is a clang bug.

Comment: the parameter auto& does not allow lambda. It needs to be (auto a)

Comment: @Hemil: You are nearly right :-) It did not allow a temporary :-) So auto&& or auto is ok but also auto func=[](){};test(func); which works fine with auto&. Will fix it!

Comment: Worth mentioning this is a clang bug, if you think that's the case.

Comment: @cigien meaning?

Comment: The parameter could be `std::invocable auto a` if you want the same constraint as `std::function`

Comment: @Hemil If the code shouldn't compile, then clang accepting it is a bug.

Comment: @cigien I had a discussion on #include forum on discord. I was informed: `A constexpr function must have at least one set of inputs that are able to be evaluated in a constant expression - otherwise it's ill formed
no diagnostic required*`

Comment: @Hemil Ah, that seems to apply in this case, so it's IFNDR, and so not a bug. You might want to write that as an answer, or suggest that Klaus edit their answer.

Comment: @cigien yes. Exactly

Comment: @Hamil:I added your finding to my answer in hope it is ok for you. feel free to write it as an own answer, so I will remove it from mine...